AWSのCloudFrontとS3を用いたサーバレスwebアプリケーションに、Cognito認証をかけたい
CloudFront + S3で実装したサーバレスwebアプリケーションにCognitoの認証機能を実装したいと考えています。
▪️実現したいことは以下です
・S3にデプロイしたwebアプリケーションにCloudFront経由でアクセスする際に、Cognito認証を行いたい。
・Cognito認証が失敗したら、CognitoのHosted UIにリダイレクトさせたい。
・Cognito認証が成功したら、Cognitoのアプリケーションクライアントに設定したコールバックURLにリダイレクトさせたい。
▪️これを実現するため、以下の手法を取りました
・cognito-at-edgeライブラリを用いてCognito認証用のLambda@Edgeを実装する。
・実装したLambda@EdgeをCloudFrontのビューアーリクエストのトリガーに設定する。
▪️発生した問題は以下です
・Cognitoに設定するコールバックURLを絶対URI形式で設定し、実際にCloudFrontに対してアクセスを行うと、Lambda@Edge実行時に「redirect_mismatch」エラーが発生し、リダイレクトしたCognitoのHosted UI上にエラーメッセージが表示される
上記の問題により、CognitoのコールバックURLにフルパスが設定できません。そのため、現在はコールバックURLにドメインまでを設定することで対応しています。(例:https://www.mydomain)
これはcognito-at-edgeの仕様であると考えていますが、この問題についてより良い解決策があれば、ご教示いただきたいです
